# How can I test multiple APIs with Postman?

Tags: postman

I am working on several apis at the same time, with different urls, endpoints, etc.

I'd like to run postman in a different environment depending on which api I'm working on.

Ideally, each environment would allow the use of different collections, env variables, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create collection for each environment :

[Add Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNn3v.png)

[New Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rNkg.png)

and then use them for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Create a new collection/folder in the postman.
2. Organize the APIs in the order they should be executed (for eg: API 'A' followed by 'B' if you want to run the API 'A' before 'B').
3. Run the collection runner
4. You will get the result which APIs have failed and which have passed.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on several apis at the same time, with different urls,
>   endpoints, etc.

As I understand your question, you essentially have a couple of requests and want them all to run in **one scenario all together, targeting different url's**, because they logically "belongs together". For this I would create an environment for that scenario, and include one entry for each API url so each request can target their corresponding url.

This builts on the fact that you can in your url definition specify environment variables, which is very handy!